# SVG cracks in Firefox (not rendering clear)

Tags: html, image, svg

My SVGs are not rendering clearly in Firefox. Other browsers such as Chrome, Opera, and Safari seems to render fine. My Firefox version is 72.0.1

I'm displaying my SVG as:

```
<img src="assets/name.svg"/>
```

This is how it looks in the Opera Browser:
[image: Opera screenshot]

And here is how it looks in Firefox:
[image: Firefox screenshot]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on how you display the svg, you are putting it inside an img tag, which actually works, but the thing here is, the svg edges are not rendered sharp in Firefox.

As a workaround  you can link to an SVG file and also retain the ability to affect its parts with CSS by using object tag.

```
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="wtf.svg" class="svg-logo">
  <!-- wtf.svg will render here -->
</object>
```

This will work fine in Firefox.

*Note: this will also work fine in Chrome, Opera, Safari.

Comment: Thank you so much, you solve my problem. I'm solving my problem for months, and you solve it. Thanks man

Comment: I'm glad that I've help you figure it out. Welcome :)